# Excel - check if a value is within a number of ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm a noob.
I would like to make Excel find out whether a value is within any of a set of specified ranges. See enclosed picture for my best effort this far. Doesn't work, unfortunately.
[image: Snapshot]

Answer (score 1):

Use `COUNTIFS`:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(D:D;"<="&A2;E:E;">="&A2);"Yes";"No")
```

[image]

If your version of Excel supports Dynamic Arrays:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(D:D,"<="&A2:A9,E:E,">="&A2:A9),"Yes","No")
```

Comment: Very good, that worked! Now I will try to understand how and why. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Basically: it's comparing `A2` to each row in columns D and E to see if `A2` falls between D and E.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone interested to make it dynamic (spill array approach) then could go with `BYROW()`.

```
=BYROW(A2:A8,LAMBDA(x,IF(MAX(($D$2:$D$8<=x)*($E$2:$E$8>=x))=1,"Yes","No")))
```

[image]